# room LiveData how to ignore some properties change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm using `room` query and return `LiveData` to display elements on UI. The problem is the entity changes most of the properties very often which isn't relative to the UI and due to the UI refreshed many times brings no good.

What I want is like swift combine `@Published`.

Here is the code:

```
@Entity
@Parcelize
data class Foo(@PrimaryKey var code: String,
                     var p1: Double,
                     var p2: Int? = null,
                     var p3: Int? = null,
                     var p4: Double? = null,
                     var p5: Int? = null,
                     var p6: Double? = null,
                     var p7: Int? = null
                     ): Parcelable
```

Actually I only care about `code` property changes insert/delete.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE code IN (:fooIds)")
    fun getLiveDataListBy(fooIds`: List<String?>): LiveData<List<Foo>?>?
```

I have the property in ViewModel and observe it in fragment.

```
var foosLiveData: LiveData<List<Fool>>? = null
viewModel.foosLiveData?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
      adapter.foos = it
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
})
```

The `p1` to `p7` properties are keep changing. Due to the list refresh all the time.

Right now, I could improve it by checking

```
if (adapter.foos != it) {
     adapter.foos = it
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

But this almost no improvement.

then if might be improved by this: (I haven't tested)

```
         adapter.foos = it
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

this could be works, but it will keep check the `map`, only might take `adapter.foos.map { a -> a.code }` out to save a bit.

This might another workaround.

I also thought take the `code` out and use a new variable `var codeObserver: MutableLiveData(List<String>) = MutableLiveData()`

Then

```
viewModel.foosLiveData?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
       viewModel.codeObserver.value = it.foo.map { it.code}
    })

viewModel.codeObserver.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
          adapter.foos = viewModel.foosLiveData?.value
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Well, I haven't test the above code, but looks like not right direction.

So any better or right way to achieve observe only one or few properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid reloading the recycler view adapter by using AsyncListDiffer. Refer to [Google's Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/AsyncListDiffer) for further information. In simple words, it can consume the values from a LiveData of List and present the data simply for an adapter. It computes differences in list contents via DiffUtil on a background thread as new Lists are received.